# Testing user_birthday permission - FB Graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ios-sdk, facebook-graph-api-v2.0, facebook-permissions

I'm trying to test possible responses from the user_birthday permission. From the docs:

> "[user_birthday permission] may or may not include the person's year
>   of birth, dependent upon their privacy settings"

I'm trying to recreate this scenario. In my test user account I have set the privacy settings of date of birth and year of birth to 'only me' however user_birthday still returns full date of birth.
Does anyone know under what conditions prevent data being returned?

I know it's possible for nothing to be returned because yesterday a real user testing my pre production app was routed to an alternative mechanism within the app to collect their date of birth because the user_birthday permission didn't return anything.

Thanks for any responses!

**UPDATE:**
So I submitted a bug report to FB to ask them to make their docs more clear on this and they told me "*we don't expose the exact conditions as to how* [the birth year not being returned] *can happen other than general 'privacy settings', since that in effect may give away something about the users privacy setting.*"

If anyone knows what exact conditions they're talking about then please share!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't really understand why this is the case but basically Facebook don't want you to know under what exact conditions the users birth year is not returned.

Conclusion: just make sure your app can handle the birth year not being returned.